# What is the Longest Meaningful Sentence U can make Using single letters only?

Tags: word, no-computers, open-ended, letters

Some Examples:

I C U.

S I M A B.

Comment: These are not real sentences, to be honest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an [open-ended puzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/5373) which won't have any single verifiably correct answer.

Comment: Written in single letters and heard , should be meaningful and as long as possible.

Comment: You, Vee, see. :-)

Comment: It is my first venture outside math area..ironically the thought came to me while reading your fish question. I used to give these riddles to my kids. If the rules say no open ended questions, I concur and it should be deleted.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot delete. If somebody can delete it, it won’t waste community’s time.

Comment: Isn't there a "delete" option underneath the tags?

Comment: For some reason, it doesn’t work for me on my iPad..last time ruby is helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Here (almost) is a classic one:

> Y Y U R, Y Y U B, I C U R Y Y 4 me

Comment: Y Y = wise? otherwise I don't get it...

Comment: 2 y's = Too wise...